# How to change status bar colours separately for each ViewController?

Tags: ios7, statusbar

I'm developing an app using iOS 7 and storyboards. I have several view controllers. What I want to do is change the status bar color according to the Navigation bar color. But each viewcontroller has a different color navigation bar. I know I can change the status bar colour by adding a flag to info.plist and code like this:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
 {   
  self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];     

   UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication   sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 0,self.window.frame.size.width-20,self.window.frame.size.height);
    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
} else
{
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
}
}
```

But how do I change the color for each `ViewController`?

Comment: are you talking about [this](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to each viewCOntroller

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
  return UIStatusBarStyleDefault; // or UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
}
```

In viewDidLoad for each view controller:

```
[self preferredStatusBarStyle];
[self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
```

Also in project properties you need to set to YES this option: View controller-based status bar appearance